# Damaged Indian passport UK visa application

Tags: passports

[image]

Hi All

My wife has applied for UK tier 2 general visa and travelling to India to submit application. While we were checking documents for her we observed a small line near back cover page near binding (as shown in picture). Could you please let us know if this can cause any issue in application?  Thanks for your help.

The passport is absolutely fine and doesn’t have any other issue and binding is also perfectly fine.... it’s just this one line

This is related to visa application and also the threading hasn’t come out hence a separate question as other questions on this portal are related to threading coming off and people trying to travel with such passport and not applying visa.

Comment: This is related to visa application and also the threading hasn’t come out hence a separate question as other questions on this portal are related to threading coming off and people trying to travel with such passport and not applying visa.

Comment: Hi All - request you to kindly respond if you know anything re above query, its quite urgent. Thanks I’m advance

Comment: why is it that most questions about damaged passports are about Indian passports? They should do something about it!

Answer (score 0):

There is no guideline as such about how the passport is classified as damaged by the Ministry of External Affairs and just by looking at your passport you might be fine. However, It is very difficult to answer this question in Yes/No here. Whether you will be allowed to travel will totally depend on the immigration officer and I suggest you go to the nearest Passport Seva Kendra (PSK) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I am trying to apply for a visa and just wanted to check if they will accept this passport.