# Is the UK tourist visa on a damaged Indian passport valid if I get a duplicate passport reissued?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, india, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for the UK tourist visa from Bangalore, India where VFS Global (company that provides several visa processing services like collecting documents and sending them to the UK Consulate) gave me a 'Damage' form because the passport was 'loose' (You can basically see the line of stitching, stitching per se is intact. The situation is similar to the pic [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123391/damaged-indian-passport-uk-visa-application?fbclid=IwAR1ytrz-To8GdcaoXycPnI8N9AYpxtKE_tV190MBKKj6FL3Tev2oliN-J0Q)).

Based on me looking around the internet, I have come to know that there shouldn't be a problem with getting the visa. However, there can be an issue with immigration (based on the mood of the immigration officer, (s)he may declare it 'damaged'). So to be 100% sure, I am thinking about getting the passport reissued.

I have two questions,

1. If I don't get a passport reissued, based on your experience, will the existing passport be considered 'damaged' (do refer to the pic [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123391/damaged-indian-passport-uk-visa-application?fbclid=IwAR1ytrz-To8GdcaoXycPnI8N9AYpxtKE_tV190MBKKj6FL3Tev2oliN-J0Q), note that everything else on the passport is absolutely fine)?
2. If I do get a fresh passport reissued, will the UK tourist visa on my old 'damaged' passport still be valid? (I do know if a passport 'expires' your valid visa is still valid but how about the visa on a 'damaged' passport?)

PS - I also need a schengen tourist visa which I will be applying for after receiving the UK visa. I am travelling in the first week of November so time is also a constraint.